# D3JS more inteactive network chart node menu

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I want to do netwok graph using D3JS, i have prepared force directed graph on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xny7st2/).
But when is network more complex, graph become very messy. So I look around and I found somethink what I want implement by d3js. [ZoomCharts](https://zoomcharts.com/en/) in this chart on homepage is context menu on every node, child nodes are loading on demand and is possible display another chart on every node (tooltip).

I´m beginer in d3js, so I will be grateful for some advice how to achieve it.

1. add context menu to nodes
2. when select some context menu item show another graph (like pie chart)
3. if it is possible load daata on demand (when user click on parent node)..

If you have ever seen somethink like that (some example code) please share!

Thanks for advice!

**Edit1:**
I prepare base donut chart for menu. I need add some hover actions and loading icons insted of text labels by icon name in data set. I will be glad if someon help me with this. This menu may helps many people.
**Edit2**: I updated menu chart, now is supported hover effect. Now it by usefull combine with force directed graph. When someone click on node pie chart menu show.

```js
var dataset = [
    {
        size: 2,
        label: "Item 1"
    },
    {
        size: 1,
        label: "Item 2"
    },    
    {
        size: 65,
        label: "Item 3"
    },    
    {
        size: 45,
        label: "Item 4"
    },    
    {
        size: 50,
        label: "Item 5"
    }
];

var width = 460,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;


var color = d3.scale.category20();
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return Object.keys(dataset).length; }); // zde je nutné zadat celkovou populaci - početz prvků v 

// Menu

// Arc setting
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 50);

// Graph space
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Prepare graph and load data
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

// Add colors
var path =  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.size);})

// Add labels
var asdfd =  g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.label; });

var oldColor;

// Add hover action
  path.on("mouseenter", function(d,i) {
              console.log("mousein"+ d.data.label)
              
              var thisPath = d3.select(this);
              
                  oldColor = thisPath.attr("fill"); // save old color
      
                  thisPath
                  .attr("fill", "blue")
                  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
                  .attr("class", "on");
     
      
  })
 
  path.on("mouseout", function(d) {
                 d3.select(this)
                 .attr("fill", oldColor)
                 .attr("class", "off");
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It will be awsome if combined result will look like this:

[image]

**I solved most of this, here is code, but I have performace problem. If someone could help i will be glad. Graph is lagging and i have problem with arrows ind end of the line. **

```js
var json = {
    "nodes": [{
        "id": -1146034065,
            "name": "/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -990073683,
            "name": "/blog/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -1724280020,
            "name": "/menu/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": 1176095248,
            "name": "/napojovy-listek/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -2085082741,
            "name": "/fotogalerie/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": 883542796,
            "name": "/rezervace/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": 369131020,
            "name": "/kontakt/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -1276353015,
            "name": "/en/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -1557747058,
            "name": "/o-nas/",
            "group": 404
    }, {
        "id": 890427810,
            "name": "/en/about-us/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -978700858,
            "name": "/en/menu-2/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": 1436673749,
            "name": "/en/napojovy-listek/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -489730654,
            "name": "/en/photograph/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": -1461616187,
            "name": "/en/reservation/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": 1520755615,
            "name": "/en/contact/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": 37644686,
            "name": "/en//kontakt/",
            "group": 0
    }, {
        "id": 1131720527,
            "name": "/en//o-nas/",
            "group": 404
    }],
        "links": [{
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 369131020,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1276353015,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1557747058,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 890427810,
            "target": -990073683,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -978700858,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1436673749,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -489730654,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1461616187,
            "target": 883542796,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1520755615,
            "target": 369131020,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 37644686,
            "target": -1276353015,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1131720527,
            "target": -1276353015,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": -990073683,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "count": 3,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "count": 3,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "count": 3,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": 883542796,
            "count": 3,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": 369131020,
            "count": 3,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": -1276353015,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1146034065,
            "target": -1557747058,
            "count": 2,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": -990073683,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": 883542796,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": 369131020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -990073683,
            "target": 890427810,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": -990073683,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": 883542796,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": 369131020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -1724280020,
            "target": -978700858,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": -990073683,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": 883542796,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": 369131020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1176095248,
            "target": 1436673749,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": -990073683,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": 883542796,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": 369131020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": -2085082741,
            "target": -489730654,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": -990073683,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": 883542796,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": 369131020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 883542796,
            "target": -1461616187,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 369131020,
            "target": -1146034065,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 369131020,
            "target": -990073683,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 369131020,
            "target": -1724280020,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 369131020,
            "target": 1176095248,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 369131020,
            "target": -2085082741,
            "count": 1,
            "value": 1
    }

    ]
}


var width = 960,
    height = 700

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["a"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var edges = [];
var fill = d3.scale.category10();

json.links.forEach(function (e) {
    // Get the source and target nodes
    var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function (n) {
        return n.id === e.source;
    })[0],
        targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function (n) {
            return n.id === e.target;
        })[0],
        count = e.count;

    // Add the edge to the array
    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        count: count,
        type: "a"
    });
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.01)
    .distance(500)
    .charge(-300)
    .linkDistance(300)
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(edges)
    .start();



var link =  svg.append("g").selectAll("link")
    .data(edges)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    //.attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.targetNode + ")"; })
    .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.count * 1, 5);
});



// Přidáme k uzlu kontextové menu a zvýrazníme sousedy
var node = svg.selectAll("node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return fill(d.group);
})
    .call(force.drag).on("mouseover", fade(.1)).on("mouseout", fade(1))
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function (d) { return fill(d.group);});
        d3.select(".menu").remove();
        
    var thisNode = d3.select(this);
    thisNode.attr('r', 25).style("fill", "lightcoral");

    var menuDataSet = [{
        size: 2,
        label: "Item 1"
    }, {
        size: 1,
        label: "Item 2"
    }, {
        size: 65,
        label: "Item 3"
    }, {
        size: 45,
        label: "Item 4"
    }, {
        size: 50,
        label: "Item 5"
    }];

    // Barvy menu
    var color = d3.scale.category20();
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) {
        return Object.keys(menuDataSet).length;
    }); // zde je nutné zadat celkovou populaci - početz prvků v 

    // Menu
    var widthMenu = 180,
        heightMenu = 180,
        radiusMenu = Math.min(widthMenu, heightMenu) / 2;

    // Arc setting
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radiusMenu - 70)
        .outerRadius(radiusMenu - 25);

    // Graph space
    var svgMenu = thisNode.append("svg")
        .attr("width", widthMenu)
        .attr("height", heightMenu)
        .attr("class","menu")
        .attr("x", -90)
        .attr("y", -90)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + widthMenu / 2 + "," + heightMenu / 2 + ")");


    // Prepare graph and load data
    var g = svgMenu.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(menuDataSet))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    // Add colors
    var path = g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.size);
    })

    // Add labels
    var asdfd = g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.label;
    });

    // Add hover action
    path.on("mouseenter", function (d, i) {

        var thisPath = d3.select(this);
        thisPath.attr("fill", "blue")
            .attr("cursor", "pointer")
            .attr("class", "on");
    })

    path.on("mouseout", function (d) {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.data.size);
        })
            .attr("class", "off");
    });

});





/*
  node.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16);
*/
node.append("circle").attr("r", 10);

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name
});

// přidá popisky k hranám
var labels = svg.selectAll('text')
    .data(edges)
    .enter().append('text')
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2;
})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.count;
});


force.on("tick", function () {

    link.attr("d", function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
);
    
    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    labels.attr("x", function (d) {
        return (d.source.x + d.target.x + 10) / 2;
    })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
        return (d.source.y + d.target.y + 10) / 2;
    })


});



function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

var linkedByIndex = {};
edges.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
}


function fade(opacity) {
    return function (d) {

        // přidá popisky k hranám
        var labels = svg.selectAll('text')
            .data(edges)
            .enter().append('text')
            .attr("x", function (o) {
            return (o.source.y + o.target.y) / 2;
        })
            .attr("y", function (o) {
            return (o.source.x + o.target.x) / 2;
        })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (o) {
            return o.count;
        });

        node.style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });

        link.style("stroke-opacity", function (o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
        });
    };
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0,4 1;
}

text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After some debate, I voted to close your question.  You are [asking too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things) [much at once](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277873/how-to-handle-multi-part-question) and you are asking in a way that won't benefit the community afterward.  I'd start more simply with a single direct question.

Comment: why not use ZoomCharts SDK as it gives you all that functionality without need to develop it. moreover, it's much faster than d3.

Comment: Simply ToomCharts is not free. D3 can be faster, when you choose canvas to rander and tha main point with D3 you can do what you want.